# Resize WPF controls in VSTO taskpane

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, vsto, wpf-controls

I want to have own WPF taskpane with listview (in Word).
I have winform host control and then I add my own WPF .
On this UserControl I have grid (with 3 rows).
In one of this row I have  with <ListView.ItemTemplate> with TextBlock

Taskpane->host->usercontrol->grid->ListView->ListView.ItemTemplate->Grid->TextBlock

I have no idea how to force to autosize this TextBlock when I am changing size od taskpane.

I know that almost every of this controls might have width property to "auto" value (minimum to fit) or "*" (fill all available space; not valid for TextBlock).
I mixed every combination ot this values and still doesn't work form me.
Now I have constans values for width property but its bad solution.

my taskpane:

```
    var wpfHost = new TaskPaneHost();
    wpfHost.AutoSize = true;
    wpfHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    wpfHost.WpfElementHost.HostContainer.Children.Add(MyUserControl);
    
    var taskPane = _taskPaneCollection.Add(wpfHost, "TEST", window);
    taskPane.Width =   2 * window.Width / 5;
    taskPane.Visible = true;
```

```
<UserControl (...)
     MinHeight="400"
     MinWidth="350"
     Width="Auto"
     Height="Auto"
(...)
<Grid>
    no references to width
(...)   
<ListView Grid.Row="2"
    Height="Auto"
    Width="Auto">
(...)
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <Grid>
(...)
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    Width="Auto"
    MaxWidth="350"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    TextAlignment="Left"
    >
```

If I remove MaxWidth="350" from textblock then text inside isn't wrapped.

How to make the text in textblock will be still visible after resizing taskpane, and occupied the entire visible area?

[image]

Comment: How are the column definitions of the `Grid` defined?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to change the column definition of your grid WPF control (a child of the user control).

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <!-- other content for rows -->
</Grid>
```

See [ColumnDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.columndefinition?view=winrt-22000) for more information.

To wrap the text in the textbox control you need to set the following property:

```
TextWrapping="Wrap"
```

Comment: I tought about it but in this case textblox doesn't wrap text and scrollbar appear on the bottom.

Comment: I don't know how to depend maxwidth of textblock with grid width.

Comment: Have you tried using the `TextWrapping="Wrap"` property in the code?

Comment: Yes. In main post I show it in my code.

Comment: Its look like Wrap works only with fixed MaxWidth property.